# ASP.NET MVC Unobtrusive validation not working on IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, client-side, unobtrusive-validation

I am working on code written by someone else.
Its a Reset Password form. The current client side validation works on most browsers including IE 10 and IE 11. On IE 9 the Confirm Password does not match error keeps getting displayed even though I am sure I am typing the exact same thing in both fields.
The code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-phone">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
            <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" class="form-control input-lg default-focus" data-val="true" data-val-required="Password is required." placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-login-bottom">
        <div class="input-group input-pin">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
            <input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control input-lg" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="Confirm Password does not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></div>
    </div>
```

I searched a lot yesterday but none of the solution seems to work.
I tried: updating the jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js files.

I tried debugging, in the jquery.validate.js file, this snippet,

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo
    equalTo: function( value, element, param ) {
        // bind to the blur event of the target in order to revalidate whenever the target field is updated
        // TODO find a way to bind the event just once, avoiding the unbind-rebind overhead
        var target = $(param);
        if ( this.settings.onfocusout ) {
            target.unbind(".validate-equalTo").bind("blur.validate-equalTo", function() {
                $(element).valid();
            });
        }
        return value === target.val();
    },
```

**target** is the input field with `id Password`. On IE 10 and IE 11, alerting `target.val()`
returns the correct value of type in. On IE 9 it returns empty. Cannot figure out why it does not work on IE 9 specifically. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

What versions of jQuery, jQuery validate and ASP MVC are you using?
I just created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tv2obdq/6/) using your html and including the latest versions of those libraries (jquery 2.1.0, validate 1.13 and validate-unobtrusive from MVC 5). I verified the validation works on IE9 (Mine is version 9.0.8112.16421)

However I have found [this issue](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/issue-with-jquery-validation-plugin-on-ie9) which means you may find this error in IE9 with incorrect html on your page. You could make sure you don´t have any open tags (like a `<p>` without its corresponding `</p>`). For example if in the fiddle you just add a `<p>` right before the `<form>` the validation stops working in IE9 but not in Firefox. (See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eeduuru/) that doesn´t work on IE9)

In case this doesn´t help, I would check the library versions and any other library that you might be loading in your page that could interfere (If you could replicate your issue in a fiddle that would be great!). If nothing helps, you can try removing the validate-unobtrusive library from the fiddle (it is added on external references) and uncomment the JS code to manually use the validation plugin. At least that would let you find out if the issue is related with jquery.validate or with Microsoft´s jquery.validate-unobtrusive:

```
//This is commented in the fiddle. Only uncomment to try jquery.validate without jquery.validate-unobtrusive
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testForm").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            Password: {
                required: true
            },
            ConfirmPassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#Password"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // just for the fiddle demo
            alert('valid form submitted');                 
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your 'working' jsfiddle works perfectly. I looked at 'incorrect' jsfiddle. I can see that the validation stops working completely. The issue I have is not that. What happens for me is that even if I type the same thing in both fields it shows the error message saying that they do not match. The jquery version I am using is v1.11.1 and the jquery validate plugin is version 1.11.1. I am not sure about the version for the unobtrusive. Thanks for your suggestions. I will try to create a jsfiddle that replicates the issue.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC version is 5.2.0.0

Comment: I have created an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tv2obdq/7/) with jquery 1.11.0, jquery.validate 1.11.1 and the latest unobtrusive. If this works too, there must be something else on your page interfering (another JS library or the rest of the html code)

Comment: The updated fiddle works correctly. Still not able to reproduce the issue. There are a number of javascript libraries being used in the project. I will be checking each of them to see if they could be the source of the issue. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Could it be jquery.placeholder one of those libraries? See [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/issues/142). By the way, you don't have any errors logged in the console isn't?

Comment: I have tried jquery.placeholder on IE9 and I have seen the same behaviour you are experiencing (entering the same exact password is not recognized as valid). I added that plugin on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ep1Lb6vy/3/) and the validation is broken. (I dont get any validation at all, although the exact same issue you see doesn't seem to be consistent. This might be because I am using IE10 in IE9 mode, I can't try on real IE9 until later today). Could you confirm if you are using this plugin?